# What is the order precedence of a = b == c in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, equals, operator-precedence

```
var clicked = $(event.currentTarget || target);
var clickedIsActive = clicked[0] == this.active[0];
```

I'm fairly new to js, and while attempting to read through some jQuery code, I came across the above section.

What is the precedence for the second line?

Is it:

```
var clickedIsActive = (clicked[0] == this.active[0]);
```

Or is it something else?

Thank you.

Comment: The only operator that has a higher precedence than an assignment is the comma operator, e.g. `foo = 0,1;` is interpreted as `(foo = 0),(1);`

Answer (score 7):

Yes, the rightmost side of an assignment is evaluated first.

`clickedIsActive` is assigned the result of the expression `clicked[0] == this.active[0]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
var clickedIsActive = clicked[0] == this.active[0];
```

clickedIsActive is the result of comparing `clicked[0] == this.active[0]` so `clicked[0] == this.active[0]` would have to be compared first.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be confusing the `=` with the `==`. They're not the same thing so this is very much like comparing apples with oranges.

`=` is an assignment. `==` is a "is equal" comparison that will only return `true` or `false`.

Misunderstanding or not, your transcode is correct. The right side of an assignment is parsed before the actual assignment. The Javascript VM needs to know what it's assigning something as before it can save it.